# Is there a way to have bootstrap autocomplete text field without any third party plugin?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I would like to create autosuggest search, when typing in text input field, it search inside an array and display results in list that appear, with possibility of selecting result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no built-in autocomplete in Bootstrap. So either use a plugin or code it yourself. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) has a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocompletes are pretty simple to put together yourself with jQuery.

I did this in 15-mins. It's a bit rough, so you will need to modify it to your requirements and finish it, and I used SCSS instead of CSS, so you may want to change that too.

Please see this demo: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y17rpvfb/49/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="query" autocomplete="off">
    <ul id="query-results"></ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var arr = ["Martin", "James", "Jamie", "Jameson", "Jamelia", "Jamela", "StackOverflow"];

$('#query').on({
    "focus": function() {
    $(this).parent().css('border-color', '#CCCCCC');
  },
  "blur": function() {
    $(this).parent().css('border-color', '#EEEEEE');
  },
  "keyup": function() {
    var results = [];
        var val = $(this).val();
    var $queryResults = $('#query-results');
    var queryResultsMarkup = "";

    if (val.length > 1) {
            $queryResults.html("").hide();
            $.each(arr, function(i) {
                if (arr[i].match(new RegExp(val,'i'))) {
                    var $li = $('<li/>')
                        .html(arr[i])
                    .attr('data-value', arr[i]);
                $queryResults.append($li).show();
            }
        });

        $('li').on('click', function() {
            var selectedVal = $(this).attr('data-value');
            $('#query').val(selectedVal);
            $('#query-results').html("").hide();
        });
    } else {
            $queryResults.html("").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.autocomplete-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 42px;
    border: solid 1px #EEE;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;

    #query {
      height: 42px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      font-size: 13px;

      &:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }
    }

    #query-results {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 36px;
      left: -1px;
      right: -1px;
      border: solid 1px #CCC;
      min-height: 50px;
      max-height: 100px;
      overflow: scroll;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 10px;

      li {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 13px;

        &:hover {
          background: #EEE;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
    }
}
```